# Incorporating wiki style documents in site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, wiki

Hi I have to incorporate wiki style documents in my site, with links embedded in text and date of updates in plain view, for each entity. Entity can be people, place etc. Only authorized user of site can add/edit documents.

I have to implement it using .net and SQL-Server at back-end.

I am totally blank on this. Can you please help me with **Links, tutorial and/or your answers** that how can I achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [WikiPlex](http://wikiplex.codeplex.com/), the wiki engine behind Microsoft's [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/):

> WikiPlex is a regular expression based wiki engine that allows
>   developers to integrate a wiki experience into an existing .NET
>   application seamlessly and with little effort. Built and used by the
>   CodePlex team, WikiPlex has been thoroughly tested in real-world
>   scenarios!

Comment: Thanks Christian, this starts making sense now. WikiPlex is good tool.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has an out of the box wiki if you happen to have that available already. If you're coding it from scratch, I would personally start by defining all of the use cases, then modeling the database to meet those needs. Then build your data I/O layer and user interface on that. Since you're using ASP.NET you can take advantage of the asp.net forms authentication and user and role infrastructure. The question sounds a little broad for me to really get detailed on anything.

Comment: Thanks @xr280xr, You are right that question is broad. I am clear that I need Wiki style documents but I don't know how. That is why I wrote that if someone can help me with links that from where I start gathering information about it.